# To create a dictionary of data retrieved from the database

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am working on an Entity framework MVC application with SQL Server database.

I have a dictionary structure of type dict(string,List of string) from the table,something like:

```
var dict = { "Apple",["Red","Blue","Green"],
             "Orange",["Orange","Pink","Lavender"]
             "Mango",["Yellow","Brown","Indigo"]
           }
```

Also I have another list of colors [Red,Blue,Pink].

```
var lstColors = ["Red","Blue","Pink"]
```

What is the most efficient way of creating a structure of only those in the second list from the first list like this below.

```
var finalDict = {
                  "Apple",["Red","Blue"],
                  "Orange",["Pink"]
                 }
```

Comment: What has this to do with Entity Framework? It seems both collections are in memory

Comment: "Most efficient" in terms of memory usage or execution time or readability or...? What are your criteria?

Comment: Please don't use not compiling pseudo code. I have no idea what a _" list of colors [Red,Blue,Pink]"_ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to understand your pseudo code, but you want this:

```
List<string> colorList = new List<string>{"Red","Blue","Pink"};
Dictionary<string, List<string>> finalDict = dict
    .Select(kv => new
    { 
       Fruit = kv.Key,
       MatchingColors = kv.Value.Intersect(colorList).ToList()
    })
    .Where(x => x.MatchingColors.Any())
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Fruit, x => x.MatchingColors);
```

All collections are in-memory, so this is LINQ-To-Objects and not related  to Entity Framework.